# Why is there variation in number regarding entering the land?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash

In some situations, the Torah, when issuing a commandment regarding being in Israel uses the singular and in other cases, the plural:

Dev 26:1 -- וְהָיָה֙ כִּֽי־תָב֣וֹא אֶל־הָאָ֔רֶץ
Bam 15:2 --  כִּ֣י תָבֹ֗אוּ אֶל־אֶ֙רֶץ֙
Vay 25:2 -- כִּ֤י תָבֹ֙אוּ֙ אֶל־הָאָ֔רֶץ

I did a quick count through the Chumash and found "el-(ha'a)(e)retz" is preceded by the plural 6 times and the singular, twice (once with a vav, once without).

Is there any rule or reason for the use of tavo or tavo'u in each case?

Comment: Couldn't you ask more generally why some mitzvot are phrase singular and some are phrased plural? Which would also be a good question.

Comment: @Avraham I could but I was hoping that a limited scope might lead to a specific and local answer.

Comment: The singular times are only in Devarim and the plural times are only in the other chumashim. Perhaps Moshe when he repeated it said it in singular for some reason.